# How do I use nginx to rewrite all links start with www.example.com/page to www.example.com/new-page

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect all request to

[www.example.com/page](http://www.example.com/page)

to

```
www.example.com/new-page
```

That means to replace `www.example.com/page` with the new one, for instance:

```
www.example.com/page
301 > www.example.com/new-page

www.example.com/page/1
301 >www.example.com/new-page/1

www.example.com/page/1.png
301 >www.example.com/new-page/1.png?1

www.example.com/page/common/1.png
301 >www.example.com/new-page/common/1.png?1

www.example.com/page123
301 >www.example.com/new-page123
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Use the `rewrite` directive. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use rewrite with a `redirect` param like

```sh
location /page/ {
        rewrite ^/page/(.*)$ /new-page/$1 permanent;
    }
```

My Testing

```sh
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Feb/2022:10:20:42 +0000] "GET /page/test/123 HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "curl/7.74.0" "-"
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.21.6
< Date: Sat, 12 Feb 2022 10:20:42 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Location: http://127.1/new-page/test/123
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host 127.1 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://127.1/new-page/test/123'
* Found bundle for host 127.1: 0x561d293f5970 [serially]
* Can not multiplex, even if we wanted to!
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host 127.1
* Connected to 127.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /new-page/test/123 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
>127.0.0.1 - - [12/Feb/2022:10:20:42 +0000] "GET /new-page/test/123 HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "curl/7.74.0" "-"

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.21.6
< Date: Sat, 12 Feb 2022 10:20:42 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 3
< Connection: keep-alive
<
OK
```

Comment: How do I make sure that is a 301 redirect?

Comment: Use `permanent` instead of `redirect`. Changed my answer. See the documentation (as mentioned by @richard-smith) https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite

Comment: I notice that you put a `/` in the last position of string `/new-page/`, will that redirect `www.example.com/page123` to `www.example.com/new-page/123` instead of `www.example.com/new-page123`?

Comment: No - as you described. I would always use the tailing `/` to make use `/page/` matches excatly page. `www.example.com/page123` will NOT fit the `/page/` location. IF THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT (VERY DANGEROURS) delete the tailing `/` from the location `/page` as well as the  rewrite `rewrite ^/page(.*)$`. `/page123 -> /new-page/123`

Comment: Thanks for the testing and updates. Just wondering, why it is very dangerous? Would you please give me an example?

Comment: It is mainly because it will catch everything that starts with `/page` like `/page123` /page-123`. If you want it is a little bit out of control. `/page/` will just work in the first part of the URI is `/page/` and then we have a great control over the rewrite. I have seen a couple of support cases where users had strange behaviour becuase of an missed tailing slash. But its like with everything else. If you are aware of what you are doing - you can use  it. If that was the answer to your question would appreciate if you could mark it as answer. Lmk if you more information.

Comment: Just one more thing: Why not use `return` but `rewrite`? Are they interchangable?